# Unable to find host using java InetAddress but able to find using curl

Tags: java, curl, elasticsearch, network-programming

I have a elasticsearch instance running inside a private network. when I tried to access it using InetAddress, it gives an error: java.net.UnknownHostException:

```
TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings)
                .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress
                        .getByName("http://elasticsearch.myorg.net"), 9200));
```

However, when i tried to access it using curl command, I am able to get the response.

```
curl http://elasticsearch.myorg.net:9200
```

What could be the reason that might cause this issue?

---

A workaround for me was to use resttemplate https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html.

It's a pretty neat and simple solution.

Comment: Have you tried removing the _http://_ part of the name? Maybe proxy settings are getting on your way ?

Comment: i shouldnt need a proxy since i am on the same privte network.and i didnt use any proxy for curl ayway...

Comment: tried removing http, doesnt work either

Comment: `getByName` requires a hostname, in this case `elasticsearch.myorg.net`.  If you can `ping elasticsearch.myorg.net` and `nslookup elasticsearch.myorg.net` it should work.

Comment: That's the problem, I cant ping it, only curl works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use port 9300 instead of 9200.  9200 is for the REST api, 9300 is for inter-cluster communication and Transport Client.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/transport-client.html

Comment: Not sure where you saw this information. I tried that using 9300, and the response is:This is not a HTTP port.

Comment: The docs at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_talking_to_elasticsearch.html mention port 9300 as the port to use with the Transport Client

Comment: For curl and and browser requests, use 9200.  For Transport Client, use 9300 in the constructor snippet you supplied.

Comment: Actually it turns out that the elasticsearch is configured to accept only HTTP request at 9200... so transportclient would not work for me in this case. I used RestTemplate and it worked fine. Still giving the credit because you have provided the right answer :)